# C# copying XPath to parenthesis

Tags: c#

I am programmer in C#. My problem is: If i copy XPath to parenthesis () then have underlined with red color (`react-root`) of the whole `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input`, because of "" is used 2 times. Only do not know what i need to get in front of parenthesis = (). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote inside XPath expressions, else you're indeed breaking the string.

```
*[@id='react-root']/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input
```